# How to find and replace every match except the first using sed?

Tags: sed

I am using `sed` to find and replace text, e.g.:

```
set -i 's/a/b/g' ./file.txt
```

This replaces every instance of `a` with `b` in the file. I need to add an exception, such that `sed` replaces every instance of `a` with `b`, except for the first appearance in the file, e.g.:

```
There lived a bird who liked to eat fish.
One day he fly to a tree.
```

This becomes:

```
There lived a bird who liked to ebt fish.
One dby he fly to b tree.
```

How can I modify my `sed` script to only replace every instance of `a` with `b`, except for the first occurrence?

I have GNU sed version 4.2.1.

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/a/b/2g' file
```

or

```
sed ':a;s/\(a[^a]*\)a/\1b/;ta' file
```

This can be taylored e.g.

```
sed ':a;s/\(\(a[^a]*\)\{5\}\)a/\1b/;ta' file
```

will start replacing `a` with `b` after `5` `a`'s

Answer (score 5):

You can do a more complete implementation with a script that's more complex:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf

/a/ {
    /a.*a/ {
        h
        s/a.*/a/
        x
        s/a/\n/
        s/^[^\n]*\n//
        s/a/b/g
        H
        g
        s/\n//
    }

    : loop
    p
    n
    s/a/b/g
    $! b loop
}
```

The functionality of this is easily explained in pseudo-code

```
if line contains "a"
    if line contains two "a"s
        tmp = line
        remove everything after the first a in line
        swap tmp and line
        replace the first a with "\n"
        remove everything up to "\n"
        replace all "a"s with "b"s
        tmp = tmp + "\n" + line
        line = tmp
        remove first "\n" from line
    end-if

    loop
        print line
        read next line
        replace all "a"s with "b"s
        repeat loop if we haven't read the last line yet
    end-loop
end-if
```

Comment: **+1** … Very nicely explained.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to replace all and then reverse the first replacement (thanks *potong*):

```
sed -e 'y/a/\n/' -e 's/\n/a/g' -e 'y/\n/b/'
```

Newline serves as an intermediate so strings beginning with `b` work correctly.

The above works line-wise, if you want to apply it to the whole file, first make the whole file into one line:

```
<infile tr '\n' '^A' | sed 'y/a/\n/; s/\n/a/; y/\n/b/' | tr '^A' '\n'
```

Or more briefly using the sed command from *potong's* answer:

```
<infile tr '\n' '^A' | sed 's/a/b/2g' | tr '^A' '\n'
```

Note `^A` (ASCII 0x01) can be produced with <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>. `^A` in `tr` can be replaced by `\001`.

This assumes that the file contains no `^A`.

Comment: What if a line only contains `baa`?

Comment: Your method still works but you have to use a unique character first i.e. `sed 'y/a/\n/;s/\n/a/;y/\n/b/' file`

Comment: I see what you mean, use newline as an intermediary nice.